# MVC 5 routes post model doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

MapRoute

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ContactForm",
    url: "contact-form.html",
    defaults: new { controller = "SiteHome", action = "ContactForm" },
    namespaces: new[] { "Presentation.Controllers" }                
);
```

Action Method

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactForm postForm)
{
}
```

Contact Form Codes

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IletisimForm", "SiteAnasayfa", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" }))
{

     @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fullname, new { @class = "w-input easing" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fullname, "", new { @class = "text-danger text-bold" })

     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Telephone, new { @class = "w-input easing")
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger text-bold" })

     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "w-input easing")
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger text-bold" })

     @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "w-input easing" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger text-bold" })

     <input type="submit" class="fr w-button easing" value="Send" />

}
```

When i post my form.. I removed AntiForgeryToken() and tested same result.

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**

Comment: What is the name of the controller the ContactForm Action is in?

Comment: Controller : SiteHomeController Action : ContactForm. Get method works but when i try for post showing 404.

Comment: How are you posting the form? Are you calling handling antiforgery token client side?

Comment: did you add the anti forgery tokens inside the form?you may missed the anti forgery tokens.

Comment: try to remove the attribute antiforgerytokens from action

Comment: I tried and same result. I changed my message and i added full contact form codes.

Comment: By default, any URL ending in an extension (i.e. `.html`) is handled directly by IIS and never even makes to the the ASP.NET MVC machinery.

Comment: I dont have experience. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionResult name "ContactForm" but you post

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IletisimForm", "SiteAnasayfa", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" }))
```

It must be;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" }))
```

And your routing like;

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And your action like;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactForm postForm)
{
}
```

And remove the AntiForgeryToken, if you post your data you can add later.

Comment: Thanks but i changed for english. I am using same controller name and action name. I want to use special url. I know it works on default route.